# show the div when user login for first time only

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website i am having content builder page, if user come to this page for first time (after login)i need to run the on-boarding screen. I had done the on-boarding section also, that working fine. what is my problem is i want run the on-boarding screen for one time only when user sign up and come to that page i need to run this, second time this should not be happen, how to do this using **session storage or cookies** can any one help give some idea that will be helpful for me..
I am not having any idea ...

Comment: So show us what you've already tried

Comment: You should always use a fallback to cookies, if SessionStorage is not supported in any of the browsers. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Start with this code:

```
// Check if session storage is available.
if (typeof sessionStorage != "undefined") {
    // Check if there's already an entry.
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("visited") == null) {
        // It's not set.
        // Show some message.
        alert("Hi!");
        // Set the visited to true.
        sessionStorage.setItem("visited", true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A basic function to set,delete, and get the cookie:

```
setCookie = function (c_name,value,exdays) {
  var exdate = new Date();
  exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
  var expires = exdate.toUTCString();
  var isIE8 = (document.documentMode !== undefined);
  if (exdays == 0) {
    expires = (isIE8 == true) ? "" : "0";
  }
  var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+expires);
  document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

getCookie = function(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
       var c = ca[i];
       while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
       if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
   return "";
}

deleteCookie = function(name) {
   document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
}
```

Then you can check the cookie to see if they visited as such:

```
if (getCookie('visited')) {
   $('.screen').remove();
   deleteCookie('visited');
} 
else {
   setCookie('visited','true',999); //999 days expiration
}
```